# Renew command in section title

Tags: macros, sectioning

I use `\secname` to store section titles and call it in `\section`. But some sections require a different title. I thought I could renew this command but I couldn't do it within `\section{...}`.

I know to solve this problem I can move the renew out of `\section`, but the code here is only an oversimplified example. The real one is more complicated with other libraries, so moving it out isn't really feasible. Instead, I would like to understand why the `\renewcommand` fails in `\section` and if there is a way to fix it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\secname}{A Section}
\section{\renewcommand{\secname}{A Big Section}\secname}
\end{document}
```

```
! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.4 ...ewcommand{\secname}{A Big Section}\secname}
```

### Update 1

One comment below gives `\protect` as a solution. But that doesn't fully fix the problem, as shown in this updated example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newcommand{\secname}{A Section}
\section{\secname}
\section{\protect\renewcommand{\secname}{A Big Section}\secname}
\section{\secname}
\end{document}
```

Compile it twice and the second will fail.

### Update 2

With some discussion I tend to focus more on why `\renewcommand` fails in `\section` rather than solving this specific `\secname` problem. This gives rise to a more interesting example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\newcommand{\mycolor}{red}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{\renewcommand{\mycolor}{blue}}                 % fails in round 1;
\section{\protect\renewcommand{\mycolor}{blue}}         % fails in round 2;
\section{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\mycolor}{blue}} % fails in round 1;
\end{document}
```

It fails even if `\renewcommand` is protected.

Comment: You can use `\section{\protect\renewcommand{\secname}{A Big Section}\secname}`. It is, however, not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: Agree with @Schrödinger'scat here—I'm very curious about *why* you're doing this. It seems this should be handled at the document class level with `\section` doing the lifting here (so your section command would look like `\section[A Big Section]{A Section}`

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Hi, that is not a complete fix. I updated question. Please check the new example.

Comment: Sorry but your example doesn't make any sense. If you can write the new name verbatim  in the section argument with `\section{\renewcommand{\secname}{A Big Section}\secname}` then why can't you simply write directly `\section{A Big Section}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The simplified code is just written that way. I should probably say *My code ...* instead of *I ...* because the code is based on other people's work. But I think using a local variable has an advantage if we need something like `\color{red}{\secname}\color{green}{\secname}` in the section title.

Comment: I don't ask about the variable in general. But if you can locally change the title to add a \renewcommand to the title, you can also change it to simply use the new title. (But you shouldn't add formatting commands there. This should be done in different place.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Right, it's a way of fixing this specific problem. But understanding why `\renewcommand` fails is also an important part of the question.

Comment: `\renewcommand` fails because a section title gets typed at least three times: in the text, in the .toc file, and in the toc itself (and a fourth time in the pdf bookmarks if you're using hyperref).  You already know that the solution is move the renew out of `\section`.  If you claim that's not possible, could you post some code showing why you can't move the renew out of the title?

Comment: @Teepeemm and also in the header ...

Comment: @Teepeemm I still have no idea why `\renewcommand` fails has anything to do with how many times it gets typed. I think the problem is about fragile and robust commands but haven't figured out what it exactly is.

Answer (score 3):

As you already noted, the way to (properly) fix it is to move the `\renewcommand` outside of the section title. If you can't do that (for whatever reason), then you can supply an alternative optional argument that doesn't use the command renewal; something resembling

```
\section[A section]{\renewcommand{\secname}{A section}\secname}
```

maybe. However, it's a bad practice since the arguments of sectional units are fragile. They end up in the ToC and headers usually, so have to be treated with care.

If you're still stuck with that idea, perhaps redefine `\section` to manage things in an automated way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \renewcommand{\secname}{#3}% Store \section name in \secname
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldsection*{#3}}% \section*{..}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
       {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% \section[.]{..}
       {\oldsection{#3}}% \section{..}
    }%
}

\newcommand{\secname}{}% Define first \secname

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
This is \secname.

\section{A big section}
This is \secname.

\end{document}
```

There are other options as well. For example, [`nameref`](//ctan.org/pkg/nameref) provides the means to extract the sectional name via `\nameref`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}\label{sec:first}
This is \nameref{sec:first}.

\section{A big section}\label{sec:second}
This is \nameref{sec:second}, but also see \nameref{sec:first}.

\end{document}
```

Since `\nameref` functions just like the regular `\ref` (with an accompanying `\label`), you can use it anywhere you would normally use a `\ref`, making it very versatile in its use. In contrast, `\secname` only is valid from that point onward, so can't be used for in a forward-style reference.